# Determine the number of roots of $f(x)=xe^x-1 $

Tags: calculus

How can I find the number of roots of $f(x)=xe^x-1$? Is this problem solvable using [Bolzano's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) and [Rolle's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RollesTheorem.html) theorems?

Comment: The zeroes may be stated in terms of the Lambert W function. It's a topic that's been discussed here quite a few times, so I suggest doing a search of MSE for it.

Comment: Note that since $x$ is increasing over the positive reals, and so is $e^x$, it follows that $f(x)$ is also increasing. Thus there is at most one positive root. Since $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=e-1\gt 0$, there is a root between $0$ and $1$. And of course there ar eno negative roots.

Comment: @Sajjad Why did you delete this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911830/test-to-check-optimal-solution ? Problems with my answer ?

Comment: @calculus No, Sorry I didn't know you posted an answer when I deleted it.

Comment: O.K. Nice to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for values of $x$ where the graphs of $y=e^x$ and $y=\frac{1}{x}$ meet.
The first function is strictly increasing and positive. The second function is positive and strictly decreasing for positive $x$. Hence there is only one positive root.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use Rolle's theorem. After convincing yourself that a root exists, and every root must be positive, note that

$$f'(x) = x e^x + e^x$$

is strictly positive for $x > -1$; in fact, $f'(x) \ge 1$ for all $x \ge 0$.  Can you finish it from here with Rolle's theorem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly can't understand how to relate it to the number of roots of f(x).

Comment: @Sajjad You mentioned Rolle's theorem; that's the tool you need.

Comment: Sorry for getting off topic, but I just saw your profile. Are you seriously planning to delete your account? It's your decision of course, but I would advise you against that route.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, and I actually submitted the request some days ago. This is something I've given quite a bit of thought to (I'm not going to say anything about it here, though - feel free to e-mail me privately).

Comment: I don't have your email address, so that's not an option. Anyway, I'm sorry to see you go, you've been a valuable contributor not only regarding answers, but also regarding house-keeping. All the best for your future endeavours.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the kind words. If you're so inclined, you can find my e-mail [here](http://mathdata.msu.edu/FD/RW/F8.html#G_B).

Comment: Got it, let's see whether I can think of something to write.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more rigorous treatment:

The function is differentiable. Compute the derivative and look at its sign. The derivative is positive for x>-1 and negative for x<-1. Thus the function is increasing for x>-1 and decreasing for x<-1.

Then plug in -1 in the function and look at the sign of f(-1). Plug in a "big" positive x and look at the sign. Compute the limit of the function for x-> minus infinity.

Using the IVT (Intermediate value theorem) and the three values of the function you computed you should be able to prove the existence of one root.

Using the monotonicity of the function in the two intervals you prove uniqueness of the root.